# Is there a way to diagnose ceiling fan 3 speed switch wires?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I have a Hunter ceiling fan (3 speed with lights, all on one switch) and the pull switch for the fan broke. So, I went to HD and got a replacement switch that looked identical, same volts/amps rating and 45 wires, same as the old one. I thought I hooked up the wires to L, 1, 2, and 3 in the same configuration as the old one, but now the fan won't turn off, and there are only two settings (high/low). Additionally, if I pull the light switch, it arcs and the breaker trips instantly (AFCI breaker). I checked all of the connections and they're good, so it isn't arcing from loose wires. Obviously I must have either wired it differently from the original one or this switch is different than the original one. Is there a way I can diagnose this without just trial and error? Is it even possible to fix, or do I need to get a new fan?

Edit: added a couple of pictures and a layout of the wires; I checked Hunter's website but they don't have a wiring diagram. I *did* find out that there was a short in the lampholder assembly itself which is/was the problem with the light tripping the breaker... but unless anybody here can help me find a "ze-301t" lampholder (alibaba sells them, minimum of 1000 pcs) then I might just have to get a new fan. For now though, it'd be good if the fan part worked even without the lights. I'll take readings with a multimeter tonight and post them.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Could you include a photo of each pull switch, making sure to capture any writing or markings on them?

Comment: I can for the new one... I dont have the old one any longer :(

Comment: Do you remember where each wire attached to the old one?

Comment: yeah, I connected the wires to the new one in the same configuration as the old one, the same color to the same indicator... I'll take some pictures when I get home later.

Comment: If you have an ohmmeter or multimeter, test the continuity through the switch after each pull. Then update this post with that information.

Comment: The first Google result for that lampholder part is https://ceilingfanswitch.com/product/zing-ear-ze-301t-lampholder/ they seem to stock it for about $12.

Answer (score 1):

Go looking for a circuit diagram for your exact model of fan (probably findable on the manufacturer's website) that will tell you how the old switch was connected, which will provide the info needed to connect the new switch. We've discussed this before, but the Android app makes searching for and linking to the previous answer somewhat annoying so I'll leave it o others to provide that link.

Comment: From my experience, Hunter (and most other ceiling fan manufacturer's) don't offer support documentation for motor housings.  I don't think they consider them serviceable, so don't offer much help to somebody trying to service them.

Comment: As I say, we had a diagram for one last year... I spent some time reverse engineering it to understand how the old switch was being used, since the new one's labelling was different.

Comment: Yeah I checked the website but the only diagram they have is for hooking it up, nothing for the internals.

Comment: Have you tried using an Ohm meter on the old switch & the new switch to determine the resistances in each switch position?  That might help you to determine how the switch is designed.